# 302 htaccess redirect from old php page to new url

Tags: php, .htaccess

Let say I have an old URL http://abc.com/x.php?a=xyz&b=jkl I need to redirect all the request to page x.php either having query string or not to http://xyz.com/x/

Below is the .htaccess file which is present in root of http://xyz.com

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(application|modules|system) - [F,L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $0 !=server-status


# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the htaccess file in your document root, add these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?x.php$ /x/? [L,R=302]
```

Note that if you have rules to rewrite `/x/` ***back to*** `/x.php`, these 2 rules will conflict and cause an internal loop. You can prevent the loop by including a:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
```

right above the above `RewriteRule`.

Comment: My URL is like http://abc.com/test/index.php?a=xyz&b=jkl and I want this url to be redirected to http://abc.com/test/  I am making switch to framework based website from simple php website.

Comment: @SushantPrasad and what do you want to have that redirected to? (Why didn't you just ask this to begin with?)

Comment: Your code is working its redirecting to specified URL /x/ but its showing 500 Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: @SushantPrasad did you follow the bit that prevents looping?(which results in a 500 error)